# Bigcartel - Removing sidebar headers

Tags: html, css, web, bigcartel

On my website [Here](http://pafclub.bigcartel.com/products) on my sidebar I have pages named 1-14. What I would like to know is how to remove the names of those pages showing up in the sidebar.

Thanks.

Comment: disable as in hide with css, completely remove from the dom, or have 1-14 grayed out with no redirect action?

Comment: 1-14 fully removed from the sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're choosing to hide more pages than you're showing, in this case you may want to just pick what pages to show, and hide the rest. Head to the Layout section in Customize Design, and find this code:

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
  <li class="title">
    <a href="{{ page.url }}" class="{% if page.full_url contains page.url %}current{% endif %}">
      {{ page.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then add an `if` statement to only show a page like so:

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
  {% if page.name == 'Entry' %}
    <li class="title">
      <a href="{{ page.url }}" class="{% if page.full_url contains page.url %}current{% endif %}">
        {{ page.name }}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to show more than just the Entry page, you can add more to the `if` statement:

```
{% if page.name == 'Entry' or page.name == 'Another page' %}
```

Another option is modifying the `for` loop to only show the first page that's listed in Customize Design > Pages:

`{% for page in pages.all limit: 1 %}`